# How to measure performance of Angular code

Tags: angular

in my Angular apps I love to use a simple utility library that is a class with some Array utility methods like isEmpty, isNotEmpty, etc.
Usually I expose the library to the template creating a field like this:

```
import {ArrayUtils} from 'common-utils/array-utils';
...
class ComponentName {
     ArrayUtils = ArrayUtils
```

and then I use it where i need it, for example in If conditions, etc.

Is it possible to measure if a code like

```
<div *ngIf="ArrayUtils.isEmpty(array)"></div>
```

is slower or significantly slower than something like this

```
<div *ngIf="array?.length"></div>
```

Thank you